# How should I respond to questions about current vet when filling out an application for a rescue if I do not currently have any pets?

Tags: adoption, shelter, veterinarian

While I have had pets in the past I currently do not have any and as such do not really have a vet to be a reference for me.  I notice that most rescue organizations include a request for a vet reference in their adoption application.

So how should I address the question of what vet I use?  Is there any thing I can do to demonstrate that I have considered my pets health needs even though I do not have this reference?

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning to adopt a pet, then you'll need to pick out a vet anyway.  So instead of waiting until your new pet is in your home, choose a vet and make an initial appointment now.  (The shelter will probably expect you to have your new pet seen by a vet within a few weeks of the adoption anyway.)  Or, if timing is too uncertain to schedule an appointment, at least call and ask what you need to do to register a new patient.  You can then tell the shelter "I don't have a pet yet, but I will be seeing so-and-so" (with contact info).

The shelter I adopted from asked for the name of the vet I would be seeing, not for a reference.  They don't expect people without pets to produce a reference, but they do expect you to have already made arrangements.  I suspect your shelter doesn't *really* expect you to produce a veterinary reference; that seems unrealistic for first-time adopters, and shelters are constantly trying to reach more potential adopters.  (Face it, there's a limit to the number of pets any one person can adopt, so while repeat clients are nice too, they have to broaden their search.  And I note that mine offers classes for first-time pet owners.)  If they do in fact require a veterinary reference, ask them what would satisfy them.

Comment: If the pet is and exotic (not a cat, dog or horse) talk to the rescue about recommending a vet.